# Joomla with Ajax: Fatal error: Class 'JFactory' not found

Tags: jquery, ajax, joomla, joomla2.5

Still having problems figuring out how to use Ajax and the Joomla framework together. I've created a Joomla component which I can access with:

`index.php?option=com_mycomponent`

I'm using Jquery with Ajax in `components/com_mycomponent/views/mycomponent/tmpl/default.php`:

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ajax with jQuery Example</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#generate").click(function(){
  $("#quote p").load("components/com_mycomponent/views/mycomponent/tmpl/script.php");

    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="quote"><p> </p></div>
    <input type="submit" id="generate" value="Generate!">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in the script.php file I have this:

```
<?php  
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
echo "This is the user: ".$user;
?>
```

If I don't put any Joomla framework code in script.php it works fine. But the purpose of doing this is that I need to use the Joomla framework and hence the whole point of creating a component. But I still don't understand how I need to structure the Joomla component so I don't get the `Class 'JFactory' not found` error?

Comment: is that the only code you have in the script.php? You can remove `language="javascript"` as it's not needed. and why are you using `html` and `body` tags in the default.php?

Comment: @Lodder That is the only code in script.php. However I've played around with putting some simple echo code just to verify I could get Ajax call to work (which it does). The issue is that I need to use the Joomla framework with script.php. W.r.t html and body tags, I have no idea, I assumed that was necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't end up taking too long in the end. The only file that is required is the default.php, so you can delete the script.php and other odd files you have in there.

**Default.php**

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

//$document =& JFactory::getDocument();
//$document->addScript("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js");
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
?>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="quote" style="display:none; padding-bottom:10px;">
        <?php 
          echo "<p>This is your username: " . $user->username . "</p>"; 
          echo "<p>This is your realname: " . $user->name . "</p>"; 
          echo "<p>This is your user ID: " . $user->id . "</p>";
        ?>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="generate" value="Generate!">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#generate").click(function(){
          $("#quote").show();
     });
});
</script>
```

I have commented out the jquery reference in the code, seeing as the widgetkit is already loading a copy of it, but kept it there just incase.

Instead of loading another file, what this does is, it hides `#quote` div tag and when the button is clicked, it reveals it with the data inside it. In this one, I have added `realname` and `user ID` just incase.

Hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: Tried this but my Generate button doesn't do anything. Although it doesn't give the JFactory error, in fact it doesn't give any error?

Comment: @Tom: do you have the component on a live site, or would you be able to provide a download link?

Comment: wish I could unfortunately it is a development site. I can give you access but would need your ip

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct way to do this is to add a task in your controller.php file in the component.

http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_AJAX_to_your_component